# Delegate construction of object to one class

Tags: c++

If I wanted to delegate the construction of an object B to class A and restrict construction to only be done by class A, how would this be done?

I want Class A would have a method that returns an object of type B, but I do not want the client to be able to instantiate an object of type B without calling a method from an object A.

I guess I do not know what to do the constructor of class B to ensure that only class A can construct it. If the constructor of class B is private, I will not be able to construct it, correct? If the constructor is protected, the constructor will be only be accessible to derived instances, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `B`'s constructor(s) `private`, and make `A` a friend of `B`:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
  std::unique_ptr <A> make_B();
};

class B : public A
{
private:
  friend std::unique_ptr <A> A::make_B();

  B() {};
};
```

Comment: Is there any solution to this without using friend?

Comment: @jonnywalkerr:  In order to accomplish that, you'll have to give up either the constructor being private or delegation being done by `A`.  Do you want to give up either of those?  As an aside, why are you reticent to `friend`?

Comment: I just thought of this scenario as an aside. I thought `friend` was the proper answer, but wanted to test my knowledge of visibility in C++. I did not know if there was another way, which meant that I knew a little less than I thought. Thanks for the help!